# Shopware 6.4.17.2 update results in maintenance mode

Tags: shopware6

After upgrading in the backend by clicking on update button, I'm getting *"Our website is currently undergoing maintenance."* both on front- and backend. Deleted update-assets folder, nothing changed. When I go to *mydomain/recovery/update/index.php* I'm getting:

> Slim Application Error

> The application could not run because of the following error:

> Details

> Type: TypeError

> Message: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given

> File: .../shop/vendor/shopware/recovery/Update/src/DependencyInjection/Container.php

> Line: 41

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Delete `{shopwareRoot}/files/backup/auto_update/dummy`.

Then either retry the web updater or better try and [update through shell](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/update-guides/updating-shopware#update-through-shell) which is recommended and more reliable.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't see this backup folder. Just theme-config and update. Unfortunately I don't have access to the cli.

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and installed the shop new.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and i found an evil solution: Simply change line 41 in File: .../shop/vendor/shopware/recovery/Update/src/DependencyInjection/Container.php
from
$version = trim(file_get_contents(UPDATE_ASSET_PATH . \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'version'));
to
$version = "6.4.18.0";

or whatever version you need.

Hope it helps